# Vim 8.0 extended syntax highlighting for scheme

Tags: vim, scheme, lisp, vim-syntax-highlighting

I use different versions of scheme (Gambit-C and Guile) and I have written a syntax file for (most of)  Gambit-C's keywords. However I only want to use it when I am using files for Gambit-C.

Sourcing it from my vimrc does not work as the scheme syntax is sourced after my vimrc and If I source it using -s < scriptin > or -c < cmd >, it only works for the first file opened and I have to source it for each extra file/argument.

I saw [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7526/16037) solution which solved my problem partially, but I do not really want vim to use the Gambit-C syntax for **every** scheme file.
I also tried adding

```
if exists("b:is_gambit") || exists("is_gambit")
       "syntax extensions
         ....."
endif
```

and using it like was shown in the [chicken scheme vim help](https://wiki.call-cc.org/vim) but that did not work and then I realized that it did not seem to work for chicken scheme either (i.e. Setting "let b:is_chicken" in the ".vim/ftplugin/scheme.vim" file does not add chickens syntax to scheme)!!

Am I doing something wrong with the variables "(let b:is_chicken)" and (let b:is_gambit) or is there another way to make it work for selected scheme files eg making .vimrc source a file after all the files have loaded?

UPDATE: It turns out that for some reason, ".vim/ftplugin/scheme.vim" was not getting sourced  and the variable "b:is_chicken was not set (this can be checked using ":scriptnames" or "echo b:is_chicken"). I then put "let b:is_chicken" in ".vim/syntax/scheme.vim" and the chicken scheme syntax worked. This does not distinguish between different scheme files though.

Comment: How do you make the difference between the two dialects? File extension? Something in the file?

Comment: My original plan is/was to set the variable "b:is_gambit" in the -u {vimrc} file, The problem was setting the variable in the ".vim/ftplugin/scheme.vim" file for chicken does not work either. So by  setting the variable. Using a different file extension would be a bit complicated for me. Can it be done by adding something to the file that won't affect compilation? That would be a valid answer.

Comment: @romainl Sorry, I only just understood your question, I don't have a way of differentiating between the two dialects in/on the files themselves. I use different vimrc files with the "-u" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be three ways to do what I wanted, I needed to (try to) understand variables, autocmd and modelines

1. Adding to the to the vimrc that will be used for Gambit-C files (i.e. vi -u {vimrc} [Gambit-C files] ) any one of the following

   ```
            let g:is_gambit=1  "" This works on all the buffers
   ```

or

```
            :autocmd BufRead *.scm let b:is_gambit "" This works for all the buffers but is redundant given the above.
```

and placing the syntax file of the form

```
   if exists("b:is_gambit") || exists("is_gambit")
         "syntax extensions
            ....."
   endif
```

as set up above to ".vim/after/syntax/scheme.vim".

Note: Setting b:is_gambit in the -u {vimrc} only sets it for the current buffer and g:is_gambit means all open (scheme .i.e. ".scm" ) buffers (if b:is_gambit is set in the ".vim/syntax/scheme.vim" it works in all buffers though). For [variables](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#internal-variables), b = current buffer  and g = global.

or......

2. Adding to the to the vimrc that will be used for Gambit-C files (i.e. vi -u {vimrc} [Gambit-C files] )

   ```
        :autocmd BufEnter *.scm source /path/to/file/gambitc.vim ""Note BufEnter not BufRead
   ```

Where gambitc.vim is the syntax file for Gambit-C.

Note: The gambitc.vim here only needs the extra syntax to be added to the scheme syntax

and......

3. As explained properly [here](https://superuser.com/a/931550/649992) setting modelines in your general vimrc and placing the Gambit-C syntax file in ".vim/syntax/" under a different name (e.g ".vim/syntax/gambitc.vim")  and sourcing the original scheme syntax by placing this in the file

   ```
          :source /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/scheme.vim
   ```

or whatever the path to the scheme syntax file is.

Then in every file you want to use the Gambit-C syntax type

```
            ;; vim: filetype=gambitc
```

i.e comment this line from the current language and then write the statement.

If there is anything wrong with any of my solutions please let me know, I personally prefer the second one as it involves less work when porting it to different machines, though I suspect using the "g:is_gambit" method is more efficient